# Communicating using only redis socketio to Php vice versa

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, redis, socket.io

Communicating using only redis socketio to Php vice versa

Im fairly new to this kind of Events in laravel, but I dont quite grasp the idea how to communicate between socketio to php using Laravel.

Im fairly new to this framework, Please be easy on me.

*I already knew how to communicate from Php to Nodejs socketio , but the problem is I dont know how the opposite communication works!*
I

**NOTE: My PHP SESSION IS REDIS**

This is my Command

```
class ChatCommand extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'command:name';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Command description';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        //

        Redis::psubscribe(['*'], function($message) {
            DebugBar::info(message);
            event(new TestEvent());
            Log::info($message);
        });
    }
}
```

My socket.js

```
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis();
var redis1 = new Redis();

//omitted some code here


http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Listening on Port 3000');
});


io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('chat', function(msg){
        io.emit('chat', msg);
        console.log(msg);
        redis1.publish('chat' , msg);
    });
});
```

I can see in `redis-cli`:

using command `subscribe *`

```
1) "message"
2) "chat"
3) "[object Object]"
```

that means `redis1.publish` works, but i dont know why i cant subscribe in my Php Laravel app"?

Comment: Maybe some sample code would help? It's called a "straw man" when you make up some code you guess could conceivably work. This helps answerers comprehend the problem quickly.

Comment: @BobStein-VisiBone ive added the Php Command from Laravel to listen for wildcard subscription of redis, and in the last line of code in my socket.js i published a chat message. but i cant get any messages why?